# Generating an Array of Vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-construction

I'm working a lot with nested lists of $(x,y)$ coordinates (of a FEM-like mesh, but that's not important), like so:

```
nodes = { {{0,0}, {0,1}, {0,2}}, {{1,0}, {1,1}, {1,2}} }
```

This has the nice convenient structure that `nodes[[i,j]]` gives me the $(x,y)$ coordinates of my "$(i,j)$th" node, so that `nodes[[i,j]][[1]]` is my $x$ coordinate and `nodes[[i,j]][[2]]` is my $y$ coordinate.  This works nicely for my purposes.

How would I construct a *variable* size array of this kind using `array[]` et. al?   If I use for instance

```
nodes = array[array[X,2],{4,4}]
```

I get a 4-by-4 array where `nodes[[i,j]]` is of the form `{X[1],X[2]}[1,1]`.  This is close to what I want, and I could change a bunch of my code to work with this, but I'd rather not - I'd love to have something where `nodes[[i,j]]` looks like this:

```
{X[i,j][1], X[i,j][2]}
```

The reason I'd like to do this is I have defined some functions that take an array of nodes as input and computes some quantity, i.e. `F[nodes_]:= (*something*)`, and I'd like to compute derivatives of this function with respect to each of its variables, i.e. $F_{x_i}$ or $F_{y_j}$.

I've tried various things with no success, and I've also tried looking for a similar construct in the documentation and here on SE, but I didn't see anything.  Any ideas?

Edit: I had too many square braces in some of my code before.  Fixed.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what is it that you want. Does `Array[{x[##][1], x[##][2]} &, {4, 4}]` work for you? Also, shouldn't `array` be upper case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler way to give an array whose $(i,j)$ element is `{X[i,j][1], X[i,j][2]}` is to just use `Table`:

```
m = 3;
n = 4;
Table[X[i, j][k], {i, m}, {j, n}, {k, 2}]
```

Output is:

```
{{{X[1, 1][1], X[1, 1][2]}, {X[1, 2][1], X[1, 2][2]}, {X[1, 3][1], 
   X[1, 3][2]}, {X[1, 4][1], X[1, 4][2]}}, {{X[2, 1][1], 
   X[2, 1][2]}, {X[2, 2][1], X[2, 2][2]}, {X[2, 3][1], 
   X[2, 3][2]}, {X[2, 4][1], X[2, 4][2]}}, {{X[3, 1][1], 
   X[3, 1][2]}, {X[3, 2][1], X[3, 2][2]}, {X[3, 3][1], 
   X[3, 3][2]}, {X[3, 4][1], X[3, 4][2]}}}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I'll have to check to see if this works when I'm back at my office tomorrow.

Comment: +1 on your answer but I prefer `Array` for this as: (1) it does not introduce additional Symbols (2) the array dimensions are adjacent e.g. `{7, 7, 2}` (3) it is easy to enter a list of dimensions, e.g. `dims = {4, 4, 2}; Array[X[#, #2][#3] &, dims]`.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this does what you requested:

```
nodes = Array[X[#, #2][#3] &, {7, 7, 2}];
```

Check:

```
nodes[[2, 3]]
nodes[[5, 4]]
nodes[[7, 1]]
```

> ```
> {X[2, 3][1], X[2, 3][2]}
> {X[5, 4][1], X[5, 4][2]}
> {X[7, 1][1], X[7, 1][2]}
> ```